# How to properly use two cookies with the same structure with GET and httr?

Tags: r, cookies, httr

I have a seemingly simple case, in which I need to download 2 cookies from one address and use them to query another address. I do it using httr, since I need auth to download the cookies, but I cannot get the usage of set_cookies in my second query right. I always get 401 Unauthorized Access response when I try.

I'm using this code to get the cookies:

```
library(httr)
r <- GET("https://example.com/sso",authenticate("user","pass"))
```

and then I can look them up, and they are of this structure:

```
cookies(r)

         domain flag path secure          expiration           name
1 .example.com TRUE    /  FALSE 2021-01-20 15:04:34    Cookie
2 .example.com TRUE    /  FALSE 2021-01-20 15:04:34 CookieExp
       
         value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
1 abc1=
2 Wed, 20 Jan 2021 14:04:34 GMT
```

However, now when I want to use them to query the other address and use the cookies for login, I get the 401:

```
md <- GET("https://example.com/api",set_cookies(cookies(r)))

> md
Response [https://example.com/api]
Date: 2021-01-19 14:41
Status: 401
```

My guess is I need to reformat the cookies, but I can only find documentation on how to do that with one cookie, and I need 2 with the same names. Any help would be appreciated as I'm stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured it out. The only needed data from the cookies dataframe are the name and value columns while the rest of the columns can be discarded. So if I make the call with:

```
md <- GET("https://example.com/api",set_cookies("Cookie"=cookies(r)$value[1],"CookieExp"=cookies(r)$value[2]))
```

then it works as desired and I get the 200 response and my content.